# Displaying XML Data to Table

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm newbie in MVC and I'm getting problem in displaying xml data to HTML table.
Please help me to configure why this not working.

```
objNodeList = objDocument.GetElementsByTagName("RESULT_ROW");
        foreach (XmlNode objNode in objNodeList)
        {%>
             <tr>
                <td><% Html.Display(objNodeList.Item(intCtr).SelectSingleNode("company_id").InnerText); %></td>
                <td><% Html.Display(objNodeList.Item(intCtr).SelectSingleNode("long_name").InnerText); %></td>
                <td><% Html.Display(objNodeList.Item(intCtr).SelectSingleNode("dt_created").InnerText); %></td>
             </tr>
             <% intCtr++; %>
        <%}
```

it display nothing except blank table.

[image]

Here's the XML data:

```
<NewDataSet>
<RESULT_ROW>
    <company_id>SC</company_id>
    <long_name>Sample Company</long_name>
    <dt_created>Sep 10 2009</dt_created>
<RESULT_ROW>
    <RESULT_ROW>
    <company_id>SC_NO_2</company_id>
    <long_name>Sample Company 2</long_name>
    <dt_created>Sep 10 2010</dt_created>
<RESULT_ROW>
</NewDataSet>
```

I'm using VS2010 MVC 2

Thank you very much...

Comment: Please show us your source XML

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace  `objNodeList.Item(intCtr)` by this `objNode` for the items.

```
objNodeList = objDocument.GetElementsByTagName("RESULT_ROW");
        foreach (XmlNode objNode in objNodeList)
        {%>
             <tr>
                <td><% Html.Display(objNode.SelectSingleNode("company_id").InnerText); %></td>
                <td><% Html.Display(objNode.SelectSingleNode("long_name").InnerText); %></td>
                <td><% Html.Display(objNode.SelectSingleNode("dt_created").InnerText); %></td>
             </tr>
        <%}
```